# Does ggplot2 work with the current version of R (v 2.15.1)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to run the R code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531904/plot-multiple-columns-on-the-same-graph-in-r)

and I get the following error:

> Error in rename(x, .base_to_ggplot, warn_missing = FALSE) : 
>     could not find function "revalue"

I wonder whether it's an incompatibility between the R version I'm using and ggplot2 (v. 0.9.3.1). Is anybody aware of this problem, or is my issue something else?

Comment: Function revalue is in library plyr. You should add this library manually with library(plyr) before plotting.

Comment: BTW, R's current version is 3.0.1 (Good Sport) released on 2013-05-16.

Comment: Ok, it worked when I downloaded the new version. Lesson learned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `ggplot2` works with the current version of `R` (3.0.1)

`revalue` is not a function in `ggplot2`, it's a function in `plyr` as pointed out in the comments.

A simple google search `function revalue R` will reveal this. Many packages depend on one another - so when you see an error like the one above, you need to use google/some other resource to find which package the missing function is from.