# Add plot legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add a legend to my plot with this dataset?
I would like to plot all variables in the same plot and identify the lines by names.

```
    Data         NO2         SO2             O3
    2004-01-01  24.49864    2.756818    30.17857
2   2004-01-02  33.40000    3.912609    22.45514
3   2004-01-03  27.55435    5.654783    24.33342
4   2004-01-04  24.87391    8.910000    30.64569
5   2004-01-05  41.96348    10.893478   44.92825
6   2004-01-06  48.80913    13.417391   44.91305
7   2004-01-07  49.10217    16.808696   28.34968
8   2004-01-08  49.14217    26.273913   16.61955
9   2004-01-09  34.52261    8.438261    17.80235
10  2004-01-10  45.33087    7.955217    36.34493
```

Comment: This must be posted on stackoverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph

Comment: In short, you have to specify `color="NO2"` in the aesthetics for the `NO2` `geom_line`, and similarly for the others, or use `reshape2`/`tidyr` to melt the data first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531904/plot-multiple-columns-on-the-same-graph-in-r

Comment: Sometimes a little search here would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gather` from `tidyr` to reshape your data frame to the long format before plotting.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# reshape to long format
datL <- gather(dat, Var, value, -Data)

# plot
ggplot(datL, aes(x = Data, y = value, colour = Var, group = Var)) +
  geom_line()
```

Here, `dat` is the name of your data frame.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

s <-
"Date         NO2         SO2             O3
2004-01-01  24.49864    2.756818    30.17857
2004-01-02  33.40000    3.912609    22.45514
2004-01-03  27.55435    5.654783    24.33342
2004-01-04  24.87391    8.910000    30.64569
2004-01-05  41.96348    10.893478   44.92825
2004-01-06  48.80913    13.417391   44.91305
2004-01-07  49.10217    16.808696   28.34968
2004-01-08  49.14217    26.273913   16.61955
2004-01-09  34.52261    8.438261    17.80235
2004-01-10  45.33087    7.955217    36.34493
"

df <- read.delim(textConnection(s), sep="")
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
df <- melt(df, id.vars="Date")
ggplot(df, aes(Date, value, col=variable)) + 
    geom_line()
```

This question is duplicated from [plot multiple columns on the same graph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531904/plot-multiple-columns-on-the-same-graph-in-r)[image]