# ggplot multiple series of percentage values

Tags: r

I'm trying to create line plots of four series of percentages using ggplot.  Sample data included below ... the output should have "Week" as the x axis and the numeric percentages for each series as a separate y-axis line plot.

I've tried to follow the instructions at [Plot multiple columns on the same graph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531904/plot-multiple-columns-on-the-same-graph-in-r).  The dataframe melts just fine but plot fails.

Data for this test:  save the following as "pct.txt" and use dget per the code provided.

> structure(list(NoRep = c("2.2%", "10.7%", "7.9%", "100%", "100%", 
>   "5.6%", "2.9%", "3%", "3.9%", "4.7%", "3.9%", "3.1%", "2%", "2.4%", 
>   "2.4%", "17.7%", "2.1%", "7.4%", "1.9%", "8%"), Report = c("46.5%", 
>   "33.4%", "36.4%", "0%", "0%", "42.2%", "43.8%", "39.2%", "36.8%", 
>   "36.1%", "36.1%", "35.8%", "37.7%", "26.6%", "26.9%", "53.4%", 
>   "39.9%", "32.9%", "40.9%", "41.9%"), Mobile_Internet = c("14.4%", 
>   "13.6%", "1.2%", "0%", "0%", "2.4%", "11.7%", "11%", "10.2%", 
>   "10.1%", "9.1%", "39.8%", "39%", "39.2%", "38.8%", "16.8%", "31.1%", 
>   "29.2%", "28.8%", "27.4%"), Mobile_SMS = c("36.9%", "42.3%",  "54.5%",
>   "0%", "0%", "49.9%", "41.6%", "46.8%", "49.1%", "49%",  "50.9%",
>   "21.3%", "21.2%", "31.9%", "31.9%", "12%", "26.9%",  "30.5%", "28.3%",
>   "22.7%"), Week = c("2018_W48", "2018_W49",  "2018_W50", "2018_W51",
>   "2018_W52", "2019_W01", "2019_W02", "2019_W03",  "2019_W04",
>   "2019_W05", "2019_W06", "2019_W07", "2019_W08", "2019_W09", 
>   "2019_W10", "2019_W11", "2019_W12", "2019_W13", "2019_W14", "2019_W15"
>   )), .Names = c("NoRep", "Report", "Mobile_Internet", "Mobile_SMS", 
>   "Week"), row.names = c("2018_W48", "2018_W49", "2018_W50", "2018_W51",
>   "2018_W52", "2019_W01", "2019_W02", "2019_W03", "2019_W04",
>   "2019_W05",  "2019_W06", "2019_W07", "2019_W08", "2019_W09",
>   "2019_W10", "2019_W11",  "2019_W12", "2019_W13", "2019_W14",
>   "2019_W15"), class = "data.frame")

```
test <- dget(file="pct.txt")

tmp <- melt(test, id.vars = "Week")

ggplot(tmp, aes(Week, value, col=variable))+
  geom_line()
```

I'm getting the error "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
adjust the group aesthetic?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message was correct, all you have to do is add the group aesthetic.

```r
library(ggplot2)

pct <- structure(list(NoRep = c("2.2%", "10.7%", "7.9%", "100%", "100%", "5.6%", "2.9%", "3%", "3.9%", "4.7%", "3.9%", "3.1%", "2%", "2.4%", "2.4%", "17.7%", "2.1%", "7.4%", "1.9%", "8%"), Report = c("46.5%", "33.4%", "36.4%", "0%", "0%", "42.2%", "43.8%", "39.2%", "36.8%", "36.1%", "36.1%", "35.8%", "37.7%", "26.6%", "26.9%", "53.4%", "39.9%", "32.9%", "40.9%", "41.9%"), Mobile_Internet = c("14.4%", "13.6%", "1.2%", "0%", "0%", "2.4%", "11.7%", "11%", "10.2%", "10.1%", "9.1%", "39.8%", "39%", "39.2%", "38.8%", "16.8%", "31.1%", "29.2%", "28.8%", "27.4%"), Mobile_SMS = c("36.9%", "42.3%", "54.5%", "0%", "0%", "49.9%", "41.6%", "46.8%", "49.1%", "49%", "50.9%", "21.3%", "21.2%", "31.9%", "31.9%", "12%", "26.9%", "30.5%", "28.3%", "22.7%"), Week = c("2018_W48", "2018_W49", "2018_W50", "2018_W51", "2018_W52", "2019_W01", "2019_W02", "2019_W03", "2019_W04", "2019_W05", "2019_W06", "2019_W07", "2019_W08", "2019_W09", "2019_W10", "2019_W11", "2019_W12", "2019_W13", "2019_W14", "2019_W15" )), .Names = c("NoRep", "Report", "Mobile_Internet", "Mobile_SMS", "Week"), row.names = c("2018_W48", "2018_W49", "2018_W50", "2018_W51", "2018_W52", "2019_W01", "2019_W02", "2019_W03", "2019_W04", "2019_W05", "2019_W06", "2019_W07", "2019_W08", "2019_W09", "2019_W10", "2019_W11", "2019_W12", "2019_W13", "2019_W14", "2019_W15"), class = "data.frame")

pct_long <- tidyr::gather(pct, "variable", "value", -c("Week"))

ggplot(pct_long, aes(Week, value, col = variable, group = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Note that including the % signs in your data means that ggplot didn't know how to properly plot the y-axis. Replacing that after loading the data is relatively trivial using `gsub`.

```r
pct_long$value_numeric <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", pct_long$value))

ggplot(pct_long, aes(Week, value_numeric, col = variable, group = variable)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: I see that removal of the percentage lines also eliminated the problem of the series not properly scaling.  Perfect!