# How do I make a single graph of multiple columns from a dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a large dataset with the daily price of gold in various currencies. The columns in the dataset are Date, USD, GBP, EURO. I want to represent each currency in a single graph. I have this so far:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = GOLD) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = USD, GBP, EURO), col ="red") +
  labs(title = "Daily price of Gold",
       x = "Date", y = "Price in Various Currencies")
```

But, having y represent each of the currencies is erroring out.

Comment: Get the data in long format and then plot. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877357/how-to-plot-all-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531904/plot-multiple-columns-on-the-same-graph-in-r

Comment: Welcome to SO, SamGray! Please make this question *reproducible*. In addition to your sample code (though please include all non-base packages ... `ggplot2` only here?), this includes the literal text of errors and warnings, sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the structure of your data frame, called `gold`:

```
str(gold)
'data.frame':   602 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Date: Date, format: "1969-12-31" "1970-01-30" "1970-02-27" "1970-03-31" ...
 $ USD : num  35.2 35 35 35.3 35.9 ...
 $ EUR : num  22.2 23.2 23.3 23.4 23.8 ...
 $ GBP : num  14.7 14.5 14.6 14.7 14.9 ...
 $ JPY : num  12592 12496 12530 12628 12858 ...
```

Then the following commands will produce the desired graph:

```
library(tidyr)   # Needed to reshape the data to longer format
library(ggplot2) # Needed to plot the data
library(scales)  # Needed to modify the y-axis tick labels

gold %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=USD:JPY, names_to="Currency", values_to="Price") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Price, color=Currency)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Daily price of gold",
       x = "Date", y = "Price in various currencies") +
  scale_y_log10(labels=comma)  # Otherwise you get scientific notation
```

[image]

---

**Data:** (available from https://www.gold.org/goldhub/data/gold-prices)

```
gold <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(-1, 29, 57, 89, 119, 148, 180, 
211, 242, 272, 302, 333, 364, 393, 421, 454, 484, 515, 545, 575, 
607, 637, 666, 698, 729, 760, 789, 820, 848, 881, 911, 942, 973, 
1002, 1034, 1064, 1093, 1126, 1154, 1184, 1215, 1246, 1275, 1307, 
1338, 1366, 1399, 1429, 1460, 1491, 1519, 1548, 1580, 1611, 1639, 
1672, 1702, 1733, 1764, 1793, 1825, 1856, 1884, 1915, 1945, 1975, 
2006, 2037, 2066, 2098, 2129, 2157, 2190, 2220, 2248, 2281, 2311, 
2342, 2372, 2402, 2434, 2464, 2493, 2525, 2556, 2587, 2615, 2646, 
2675, 2707, 2737, 2766, 2799, 2829, 2860, 2890, 2920, 2952, 2980, 
3011, 3039, 3072, 3102, 3133, 3164, 3193, 3225, 3255, 3284, 3317, 
3345, 3375, 3406, 3437, 3466, 3498, 3529, 3557, 3590, 3620, 3651, 
3682, 3711, 3742, 3772, 3802, 3833, 3864, 3893, 3925, 3956, 3984, 
4017, 4047, 4075, 4107, 4137, 4166, 4198, 4229, 4260, 4290, 4320, 
4351, 4382, 4411, 4439, 4472, 4502, 4533, 4563, 4593, 4625, 4655, 
4684, 4716, 4747, 4778, 4806, 4837, 4866, 4898, 4928, 4957, 4990, 
5020, 5051, 5081, 5111, 5143, 5172, 5202, 5233, 5264, 5293, 5325, 
5356, 5384, 5417, 5447, 5478, 5509, 5537, 5566, 5598, 5629, 5657, 
5690, 5720, 5751, 5782, 5811, 5843, 5874, 5902, 5933, 5963, 5993, 
6024, 6055, 6084, 6116, 6147, 6175, 6208, 6238, 6266, 6298, 6328, 
6357, 6389, 6420, 6451, 6481, 6511, 6542, 6573, 6602, 6633, 6664, 
6693, 6725, 6755, 6784, 6817, 6847, 6878, 6908, 6938, 6970, 6998, 
7029, 7057, 7090, 7120, 7151, 7182, 7211, 7243, 7273, 7302, 7335, 
7363, 7393, 7424, 7455, 7484, 7516, 7547, 7575, 7608, 7638, 7669, 
7700, 7728, 7757, 7789, 7820, 7848, 7881, 7911, 7942, 7973, 8002, 
8034, 8065, 8093, 8125, 8155, 8184, 8216, 8247, 8278, 8308, 8338, 
8369, 8400, 8429, 8457, 8490, 8520, 8551, 8581, 8611, 8643, 8673, 
8702, 8734, 8765, 8796, 8824, 8855, 8884, 8916, 8946, 8975, 9008, 
9038, 9069, 9099, 9129, 9161, 9189, 9220, 9248, 9281, 9311, 9342, 
9373, 9402, 9434, 9464, 9493, 9526, 9555, 9584, 9616, 9647, 9675, 
9708, 9738, 9769, 9800, 9829, 9861, 9892, 9920, 9951, 9981, 10011, 
10042, 10073, 10102, 10134, 10165, 10193, 10226, 10256, 10284, 
10316, 10346, 10375, 10407, 10438, 10469, 10499, 10529, 10560, 
10591, 10620, 10648, 10681, 10711, 10742, 10772, 10802, 10834, 
10864, 10893, 10925, 10956, 10987, 11016, 11047, 11075, 11108, 
11138, 11169, 11200, 11229, 11261, 11291, 11320, 11353, 11381, 
11411, 11442, 11473, 11502, 11534, 11565, 11593, 11626, 11656, 
11687, 11718, 11746, 11775, 11807, 11838, 11866, 11899, 11929, 
11960, 11991, 12020, 12052, 12083, 12111, 12142, 12172, 12202, 
12233, 12264, 12293, 12325, 12356, 12384, 12417, 12447, 12475, 
12508, 12538, 12569, 12599, 12629, 12661, 12691, 12720, 12752, 
12783, 12814, 12842, 12873, 12902, 12934, 12964, 12993, 13026, 
13056, 13087, 13117, 13147, 13179, 13207, 13238, 13266, 13299, 
13329, 13360, 13391, 13420, 13452, 13482, 13511, 13544, 13572, 
13602, 13633, 13664, 13693, 13725, 13756, 13784, 13817, 13847, 
13878, 13909, 13938, 13969, 13999, 14029, 14060, 14091, 14120, 
14152, 14183, 14211, 14244, 14274, 14302, 14334, 14364, 14393, 
14425, 14456, 14487, 14517, 14547, 14578, 14609, 14638, 14666, 
14699, 14729, 14760, 14790, 14820, 14852, 14882, 14911, 14943, 
14974, 15005, 15033, 15064, 15093, 15125, 15155, 15184, 15217, 
15247, 15278, 15308, 15338, 15370, 15399, 15429, 15460, 15491, 
15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 
15793, 15825, 15856, 15884, 15917, 15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 
16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 16220, 16251, 16282, 16311, 
16343, 16374, 16402, 16435, 16465, 16493, 16525, 16555, 16584, 
16616, 16647, 16678, 16708, 16738, 16769, 16800, 16829, 16860, 
16891, 16920, 16952, 16982, 17011, 17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 
17165, 17197, 17225, 17256, 17284, 17317, 17347, 17378, 17409, 
17438, 17470, 17500, 17529, 17562, 17590, 17620, 17651, 17682, 
17711, 17743, 17774, 17802, 17835, 17865, 17896, 17927, 17955, 
17984, 18016, 18047, 18075, 18108, 18138, 18169, 18200, 18229, 
18261, 18292), class = "Date"), USD = c(35.2, 34.99, 35.02, 35.3, 
35.85, 35.45, 35.49, 35.3, 35.8, 36.4, 37.25, 37.54, 37.38, 38.05, 
38.8, 38.88, 39.7, 40.84, 40.1, 42.4, 40.65, 42.6, 42.34, 43.6, 
43.55, 47.15, 48.2, 48.38, 49.6, 59.45, 64.65, 68.3, 66.88, 64.2, 
64.39, 63.6, 64.9, 66, 85, 90, 90.72, 114.75, 123.25, 115.6, 
103.5, 100, 98, 101, 112.25, 132.5, 162.5, 173, 169.25, 156.75, 
144.25, 156, 156, 151.25, 167, 184, 186.5, 175.8, 181.75, 177.25, 
167, 167, 166.25, 166.7, 159.8, 141.25, 142.9, 138.15, 140.25, 
128.15, 132.3, 129.6, 128.4, 125.5, 123.8, 112.5, 104, 116, 123.15, 
130.25, 134.5, 132.3, 142.75, 148.9, 147.25, 142.95, 143, 144.1, 
146, 154.05, 161.5, 160.05, 164.95, 175.75, 182.25, 181.6, 170.85, 
184.15, 183.05, 200.25, 208.7, 217.1, 242.6, 193.4, 226, 233.7, 
251.3, 240.1, 245.3, 274.6, 277.5, 296.45, 315.1, 397.25, 382, 
415.65, 512, 653, 637, 494.5, 518, 535.5, 653.5, 614.25, 631.25, 
666.75, 629, 619.75, 589.75, 506.5, 489, 513.75, 482.75, 479.25, 
426, 406, 425, 428.75, 427, 414.5, 397.5, 387, 362.6, 320, 361.25, 
325.25, 317.5, 342.9, 411.5, 397, 423.25, 436, 456.9, 499.5, 
408.5, 414.75, 429.25, 437.5, 416, 422, 414.25, 405, 382, 405, 
382.4, 373.75, 394.25, 388.5, 375.8, 384.25, 373.05, 342.35, 
348.25, 343.75, 333.5, 329, 308.3, 306.65, 287.75, 329.25, 321.35, 
314, 317.75, 327.5, 333.25, 325.75, 325.1, 325.3, 326.8, 350.5, 
338.15, 344, 345.75, 343.2, 346.75, 357.5, 384.7, 423.2, 401, 
389.5, 388.75, 400.5, 405.85, 421, 453.25, 451, 447.3, 462.5, 
453.4, 459.5, 468.8, 492.5, 484.1, 458, 426.15, 456.95, 449, 
455.5, 436.55, 436.8, 427.75, 396.7, 412.4, 422.6, 410.25, 394, 
387, 383.2, 377.55, 361.8, 373, 368.3, 359.8, 366.5, 375.3, 408.15, 
398.6, 415.05, 407.7, 368.5, 367.75, 363.05, 352.2, 372.3, 387.75, 
408.4, 379.5, 384.85, 386.2, 366, 362.7, 355.65, 357.75, 360.4, 
368.35, 362.85, 347.4, 354.9, 357.45, 366.3, 353.15, 354.1, 353.1, 
341.7, 336.35, 337.5, 343.4, 357.85, 340, 349, 339.25, 334.2, 
332.9, 330.45, 327.6, 337.8, 354.3, 377.45, 378.45, 401.75, 371.55, 
355.5, 369.6, 370.9, 391.75, 377.9, 381.55, 389.2, 376.45, 387.6, 
388.25, 384, 385.75, 394.85, 383.85, 383.1, 383.25, 374.9, 376.4, 
392, 389.75, 384.3, 387.05, 383.35, 382.35, 384, 382.65, 387.8, 
387, 405.55, 400.65, 396.35, 391.3, 390.55, 382, 385.3, 386.45, 
379, 379.5, 371.3, 369.25, 345.5, 358.6, 348.15, 340.15, 345.6, 
334.55, 326.35, 325.35, 332.1, 311.4, 296.8, 290.2, 304.85, 297.4, 
301, 310.7, 293.6, 296.3, 288.85, 273.4, 293.85, 292.3, 294.7, 
287.8, 285.4, 287.05, 279.45, 286.6, 268.6, 261, 255.6, 254.8, 
299, 299.1, 291.35, 290.25, 283.3, 293.65, 276.75, 275.05, 272.25, 
288.15, 276.75, 277, 273.65, 264.5, 269.1, 274.45, 264.5, 266.7, 
257.7, 263.15, 267.5, 270.6, 265.9, 273, 293.1, 278.75, 275.5, 
276.5, 282.3, 296.85, 301.4, 308.2, 326.6, 318.5, 304.65, 312.8, 
323.7, 316.9, 319.05, 347.2, 367.5, 347.45, 334.85, 336.75, 361.4, 
346, 354.75, 375.6, 388, 386.25, 398.35, 416.25, 399.75, 395.85, 
423.7, 388.5, 393.25, 395.8, 391.4, 407.25, 415.65, 425.55, 453.4, 
435.6, 422.15, 435.45, 427.5, 435.7, 414.45, 437.1, 429, 433.25, 
473.25, 470.75, 495.65, 513, 568.75, 556, 582, 644, 653, 613.5, 
632.5, 623.5, 599.25, 603.75, 646.7, 632, 650.5, 664.2, 661.75, 
677, 659.1, 650.5, 665.5, 672, 743, 789.5, 783.5, 833.75, 923.25, 
971.5, 933.5, 871, 885.75, 930.25, 918, 833, 884.5, 730.75, 814.5, 
869.75, 919.5, 952, 916.5, 883.25, 975.5, 934.5, 939, 955.5, 
995.75, 1040, 1175.75, 1087.5, 1078.5, 1108.25, 1115.5, 1179.25, 
1207.5, 1244, 1169, 1246, 1307, 1346.75, 1383.5, 1405.5, 1327, 
1411, 1439, 1535.5, 1536.5, 1505.5, 1628.5, 1813.5, 1620, 1722, 
1746, 1531, 1744, 1770, 1662.5, 1651.25, 1558, 1598.5, 1622, 
1648.5, 1776, 1719, 1726, 1657.5, 1664.75, 1588.5, 1598.25, 1469, 
1394.5, 1192, 1314.5, 1394.75, 1326.5, 1324, 1253, 1204.5, 1251, 
1326.5, 1291.75, 1288.5, 1250.5, 1315, 1285.25, 1285.75, 1216.5, 
1164.25, 1182.75, 1206, 1260.25, 1214, 1187, 1180.25, 1191.4, 
1171, 1098.4, 1135, 1114, 1142.35, 1061.9, 1060, 1111.8, 1234.9, 
1237, 1285.65, 1212.1, 1320.75, 1342, 1309.25, 1322.5, 1272, 
1178.1, 1145.9, 1212.8, 1255.6, 1244.85, 1266.45, 1266.2, 1242.25, 
1267.55, 1311.75, 1283.1, 1270.15, 1280.2, 1291, 1345.05, 1317.85, 
1323.85, 1313.2, 1305.35, 1250.45, 1220.95, 1202.45, 1187.25, 
1214.95, 1217.55, 1279, 1323.25, 1319.15, 1295.4, 1282.3, 1295.55, 
1409, 1427.55, 1528.4, 1485.3, 1510.95, 1460.15, 1514.75, 1584.2
), EUR = c(22.24, 23.2, 23.26, 23.42, 23.79, 23.54, 23.55, 23.45, 
23.58, 23.98, 24.58, 24.71, 24.41, 25.09, 25.58, 25.61, 26.14, 
26.9, 26.39, 27.92, 26.1, 27.39, 27.22, 27.93, 27.06, 28.99, 
29.51, 29.36, 30.17, 36.01, 39.03, 41.31, 40.23, 38.78, 39.27, 
38.71, 39.55, 40.81, 48.14, 51.83, 52.61, 65.04, 67.54, 63.58, 
57.35, 54.93, 54.3, 58.89, 65.95, 82.65, 100.08, 100.68, 97.53, 
92.29, 85.08, 91.61, 93.61, 90.4, 99.31, 107.71, 106.18, 98.8, 
99.58, 98.85, 92.69, 91.82, 92.63, 98.41, 94.56, 85.78, 84.59, 
83.49, 84.68, 80.12, 84.37, 85.94, 87.07, 84.52, 83.13, 75.95, 
70.12, 78.1, 83.06, 87.92, 90.21, 89.95, 97.08, 102.08, 100.64, 
97.73, 97.61, 100.32, 102.04, 107.8, 111.51, 110.18, 110.08, 
117.4, 119.82, 118.79, 113.18, 122.76, 120.43, 129.16, 132.48, 
135.68, 141.49, 122.4, 137.06, 144.84, 154.64, 148.04, 152.76, 
172, 169.03, 179.68, 190.38, 233.23, 231.45, 244.87, 299.12, 
385.01, 381.48, 321.56, 317.27, 323.09, 392.72, 372.37, 386.52, 
412.83, 404.91, 406.73, 392.41, 363.31, 357.95, 375.1, 369.74, 
386.14, 353.4, 346.87, 362.53, 349.87, 347.03, 332.94, 327.48, 
327.92, 308.91, 285.71, 318.81, 284.76, 301.04, 315.16, 388.34, 
383.37, 416.77, 423.24, 429.9, 486.07, 394.41, 410.93, 430.88, 
447.29, 431.65, 456.53, 452.93, 440.9, 416.46, 451.49, 432, 436.19, 
428.55, 421.4, 425.18, 437.24, 431.92, 412.65, 419.37, 436.4, 
421.37, 423.66, 402.45, 402.82, 400.46, 425.73, 417.93, 403.43, 
404.96, 393.64, 399.98, 375.93, 366.57, 353.9, 347.51, 364.1, 
328.64, 348.01, 329.63, 350.96, 336.16, 332.15, 349.46, 383.64, 
369.82, 345.5, 337.8, 334.76, 338.02, 346.74, 371.84, 375.9, 
373.31, 391.91, 374.28, 384.69, 372.16, 371.97, 351.76, 352.89, 
330.48, 347.7, 345.58, 360.76, 364.4, 374.62, 369.07, 341.8, 
337.87, 336.58, 332.66, 335.74, 321.64, 329.38, 321.84, 324.56, 
330.9, 310.91, 318.07, 312.36, 315.19, 332.89, 310.67, 321.26, 
316.15, 283.87, 280.65, 280.21, 265.93, 267.8, 278.03, 291.86, 
262.61, 264.8, 265.67, 251.05, 256.11, 279.75, 282.52, 288.89, 
308.46, 292.89, 280.79, 273.61, 276.67, 277.92, 250.28, 264.7, 
268.95, 261.69, 257.99, 251.28, 243.14, 246.81, 224.5, 241.25, 
254.97, 261.39, 266.67, 264.28, 270.45, 274.97, 281.13, 300.65, 
321.12, 354.79, 318.97, 298.71, 318.85, 327.89, 348.19, 335.18, 
332.98, 331.04, 317.52, 325.31, 317.59, 313.37, 313, 314.77, 
298.37, 311.1, 308.79, 297.3, 293.58, 291.35, 291.51, 289.94, 
287.07, 280.74, 294.95, 288.98, 285.63, 294.55, 290.67, 314.78, 
306.5, 304.48, 308.65, 307.01, 298.59, 293.51, 294.9, 296.14, 
294.25, 291.75, 290.49, 288.68, 310.07, 297.45, 300.81, 301.56, 
296.89, 305.23, 298.45, 298.75, 273.02, 266.62, 266.06, 284.48, 
275.71, 284.19, 284.81, 267.29, 272.95, 262.35, 246.34, 251.03, 
247.54, 254.8, 245.08, 251.3, 261.48, 258.85, 270.89, 257.55, 
253.08, 238.81, 241.22, 280.75, 284.56, 289.35, 289.56, 289.55, 
305, 289.22, 301.82, 293.56, 300.59, 298.67, 311.55, 310.08, 
312.06, 309.13, 292.31, 284.41, 290.02, 291.52, 296.81, 315.6, 
319.63, 303.89, 300.53, 321.84, 309.48, 307.68, 310.53, 327.91, 
343.18, 345.48, 342.03, 349.57, 322.5, 310.74, 318.96, 327.53, 
320, 320.72, 330.86, 342.34, 322.37, 306.86, 301.75, 307.27, 
301.3, 315.18, 342.11, 333.18, 332.26, 332.32, 330, 321.78, 318.59, 
344.78, 324.09, 322.03, 325.32, 325.1, 335.1, 334.66, 334.54, 
341.15, 320.47, 323.85, 328.06, 328.93, 337.5, 335.65, 361.05, 
353.19, 352.28, 392.53, 393.03, 420.42, 434.91, 468.38, 466.35, 
480.93, 511.25, 508.39, 479.8, 495.63, 487.09, 473.06, 473.03, 
487.87, 479.28, 500.6, 502.82, 497.13, 496.06, 489.8, 481.66, 
486.17, 492.94, 522.45, 545.71, 533.77, 570.26, 623.56, 639.94, 
589.13, 559.45, 569.96, 590.43, 588.37, 565.8, 629.69, 576.28, 
641.89, 625.7, 717.52, 749.58, 690.29, 666.55, 689.18, 666.24, 
662.32, 665.83, 681.23, 704.87, 783.13, 757.97, 775.93, 812.08, 
824.4, 886.89, 984.07, 1015.59, 897.3, 980.37, 957.37, 968.96, 
1062.8, 1047.67, 967.91, 1021.58, 1014.02, 1034.98, 1068.8, 1038.38, 
1133.26, 1259.55, 1207.42, 1234.59, 1297.03, 1179.37, 1332.26, 
1323.17, 1248.4, 1247.59, 1260.06, 1259.6, 1317.04, 1307.81, 
1380.49, 1326.59, 1327.08, 1257.21, 1226.43, 1215.05, 1244.65, 
1114.23, 1076, 917.03, 989.95, 1057.75, 979.94, 973.89, 920.28, 
874.12, 927.66, 960.43, 937.24, 929.28, 916.42, 960.45, 960.58, 
976.12, 962.99, 929.24, 948.74, 996.65, 1116.8, 1082.33, 1105.21, 
1053.28, 1086.7, 1050.98, 994.16, 1012.94, 997.99, 1034.13, 1005.44, 
975.79, 1027.49, 1136.53, 1085.52, 1122.5, 1088.79, 1188.85, 
1200.09, 1175.53, 1176.81, 1160.37, 1110.58, 1086.42, 1122.24, 
1181.63, 1163.9, 1163, 1126.01, 1089.17, 1075.11, 1103.33, 1085.35, 
1090.3, 1073.68, 1075.12, 1079.71, 1080.52, 1076.43, 1086.91, 
1118.26, 1071, 1043.5, 1033.48, 1022.17, 1072.28, 1075.34, 1118.84, 
1153.21, 1158.47, 1153.67, 1144.2, 1162.61, 1237.27, 1282.15, 
1387.88, 1362.41, 1354.32, 1324.28, 1349.44, 1429.53), GBP = c(14.66, 
14.54, 14.55, 14.67, 14.93, 14.8, 14.85, 14.81, 14.99, 15.23, 
15.6, 15.69, 15.46, 15.75, 16.06, 16.08, 16.41, 16.89, 16.57, 
17.53, 16.53, 17.15, 17, 17.48, 17.06, 18.18, 18.49, 18.5, 19, 
22.75, 26.45, 27.88, 27.32, 26.53, 27.55, 27.04, 27.66, 27.73, 
34.25, 36.3, 36.45, 44.73, 47.76, 46.23, 42.09, 41.43, 40.18, 
43.07, 48.32, 58.06, 70.54, 72.23, 69.56, 65.41, 60.44, 65.55, 
67.31, 64.84, 71.54, 79.11, 79.36, 73.88, 74.81, 73.84, 70.91, 
72.26, 76.49, 77.62, 75.72, 69.15, 68.78, 68.48, 69.32, 63.13, 
65.32, 67.61, 69.76, 71.37, 69.36, 63.01, 58.51, 69.84, 77.65, 
78.82, 79.04, 77.14, 83.29, 86.57, 85.64, 83.16, 83.14, 82.96, 
83.77, 88.15, 87.75, 88.08, 86.05, 90.13, 93.87, 97.32, 93.39, 
100.46, 98.41, 103.68, 107.38, 109.84, 116.92, 99.46, 110.7, 
117.44, 124.19, 116.22, 118.82, 132.69, 127.29, 131.87, 139.89, 
180.36, 184.01, 188.97, 230.63, 288.11, 280.25, 228.51, 229.36, 
228.36, 277.32, 262.16, 263.41, 279.27, 258.16, 262.83, 246.65, 
213.98, 221.77, 228.89, 225.53, 231.52, 220.67, 220.47, 229.85, 
237.53, 229.57, 212.02, 208.22, 205.74, 199.07, 179.57, 201.37, 
181.65, 182.1, 197.3, 239.66, 234.29, 252.39, 268.56, 282.47, 
328.62, 269.64, 279.58, 275.07, 272.67, 271.9, 277.5, 277.28, 
270.54, 255.43, 276.26, 263.45, 266.68, 264.51, 269.32, 268.72, 
277.34, 275.01, 261.84, 266.14, 278.34, 273.14, 274.62, 266.01, 
271.13, 266.44, 266.06, 258.63, 244.07, 242.56, 232.52, 239.23, 
231.19, 225.61, 218.54, 226.08, 248.05, 233.69, 231.81, 222.92, 
233.07, 226.26, 239.53, 258.45, 292.47, 285.31, 271.71, 262.23, 
264.62, 262.52, 262.31, 272.96, 276.69, 277.22, 290.52, 277.56, 
282.68, 272.24, 269.72, 257.71, 258.76, 240.29, 242.03, 238.89, 
247.76, 255.59, 255.36, 254.01, 234.59, 233.19, 228.37, 226.78, 
225.08, 221.84, 227.01, 223.53, 230.08, 240.8, 221, 228.66, 226.94, 
237.83, 260.13, 247.19, 247.05, 241.24, 223.67, 224.31, 216.49, 
201.89, 200.16, 204.89, 217.99, 195.22, 198.43, 200.1, 186.26, 
189.85, 204.51, 207.51, 212.12, 227.52, 215.34, 206.66, 202.45, 
205.14, 207.54, 188.75, 197.82, 200.97, 196.89, 189.55, 184.53, 
180.36, 186.38, 171.54, 195.9, 217.12, 220.81, 219.88, 222.23, 
230.22, 224.38, 225.81, 241.8, 253.4, 270.54, 249.78, 237.71, 
248.64, 249.85, 264.79, 252.13, 256.75, 262.17, 248.27, 256.39, 
251.55, 249.91, 251.06, 250.38, 235.41, 244.77, 244.97, 236.16, 
238.19, 240.67, 242.19, 241.92, 243.29, 239.58, 246.83, 242.62, 
242.51, 253.55, 249.27, 268.4, 261.71, 259.65, 260.77, 252.07, 
245.86, 247.45, 247.25, 242.42, 233.05, 220.97, 215.77, 215.6, 
219.8, 212.03, 209.63, 211.25, 201.02, 199.3, 200.61, 205.58, 
185.7, 176.16, 176.38, 186.45, 180.63, 179.75, 185.83, 180.05, 
177.58, 176.56, 163.27, 172.91, 174.54, 178.54, 172.98, 173.73, 
179.18, 173.11, 178.01, 167.53, 165.58, 157.78, 158.46, 181.56, 
182.28, 182.93, 180.09, 174.78, 186.01, 173.48, 175.78, 182.14, 
190.34, 184.79, 190.38, 185.09, 182.16, 189.83, 183.73, 181.03, 
184.92, 181.27, 183.92, 188.3, 192.41, 186.58, 188.22, 199.43, 
191.67, 193.19, 189.98, 199.75, 209.88, 211.66, 211.49, 223.22, 
208.96, 195.02, 202.21, 205.84, 202.56, 205.04, 215.67, 223.58, 
220.59, 211.84, 210.7, 220.59, 209.68, 220.69, 237.46, 233.54, 
227.61, 231.62, 232.52, 219.61, 213.3, 230.54, 219.08, 214.49, 
218.25, 215.24, 226.38, 229.7, 232.25, 237.2, 226.89, 223.82, 
226.13, 226.24, 228.13, 227.4, 243.86, 243.67, 240.89, 267.51, 
265.92, 286.44, 298.82, 320, 317.49, 335.53, 354.3, 348.96, 331.7, 
338.77, 327.79, 320.81, 316.56, 328.77, 322.92, 332.33, 338.92, 
337.4, 338.53, 333.2, 324.22, 327.5, 333.16, 364.69, 380.05, 
381.05, 418.84, 464.41, 488.39, 469.69, 439.78, 448.21, 467.43, 
463.43, 456.7, 496.23, 452.27, 530.81, 604.94, 637.79, 667.91, 
639.41, 596.07, 604.94, 567.45, 566.4, 586.27, 622.6, 630.93, 
716.44, 673.44, 673.05, 727.96, 735.38, 770.42, 831.07, 831.5, 
746.44, 810.72, 829.42, 842.35, 888.37, 897.71, 828.47, 867.51, 
897.72, 920.59, 933.5, 937.74, 992.08, 1113.77, 1039.93, 1066.85, 
1110.12, 985.14, 1105.16, 1108.02, 1040.53, 1016.87, 1012.25, 
1019.16, 1035.23, 1037.87, 1099.83, 1067.01, 1076.97, 1019.69, 
1050.02, 1046.48, 1052.55, 943.85, 919.79, 785.92, 867.06, 901.64, 
819.13, 824.1, 764.93, 727.25, 761.2, 791.54, 774.83, 763.08, 
745.52, 769.07, 761.27, 774.2, 750.39, 727.72, 755.24, 773.45, 
839.1, 785.56, 799.6, 768.02, 780.76, 744.58, 703.88, 737.97, 
735.44, 739.67, 705.44, 719.18, 783.79, 886.12, 860.64, 877.64, 
832.77, 987.99, 1010.77, 999.66, 1018.09, 1041.85, 942.93, 927.37, 
963.99, 1009, 995.52, 978.9, 980.83, 956.35, 961.47, 1018.01, 
956.36, 956.47, 945.74, 954.35, 945.85, 956.45, 943.72, 953.43, 
980.99, 947.13, 930.78, 925.14, 910.43, 950.85, 954.27, 1004.24, 
1005.93, 991.77, 994.13, 983.62, 1027.89, 1107.1, 1165.87, 1255, 
1205.31, 1167.66, 1128.84, 1143.42, 1201.79), JPY = c(12592.44, 
12496.35, 12529.95, 12627.65, 12858.36, 12757.88, 12764.72, 12728.16, 
12799.92, 13018.66, 13341.25, 13403.93, 13239.03, 13613.21, 13867.1, 
13892.95, 14188.38, 14594.98, 14328.74, 15153.74, 13538.98, 14059.41, 
13957.5, 14250.08, 13691.48, 14624.17, 14619.8, 14695.64, 15092.19, 
18096.15, 19085.52, 20559.69, 20090.92, 19326.34, 19410.68, 19127.31, 
19568.2, 19897.07, 22585.63, 23834.22, 24145.47, 30392.78, 32263.28, 
30535.41, 27419.59, 26534.94, 26098.24, 28232.64, 31384.58, 39453.89, 
46802.46, 47602.1, 47234.18, 44183.03, 41041.61, 46668.94, 47254.41, 
45131.84, 50150.83, 55215.86, 56029.4, 52492.53, 52067.51, 51834.86, 
48788.12, 48777.59, 49565.26, 49794.25, 47625.81, 42800.94, 43162.37, 
41975.69, 42788.35, 38950.05, 40006.82, 38873.24, 38474.65, 37717.84, 
36897.27, 33015.97, 30015.22, 33347.41, 36300.55, 38700.65, 39440.3, 
38185.75, 40377.01, 41380.39, 40936.12, 39666.76, 38285.79, 38493.04, 
39036.11, 40680.98, 40276.31, 39109.66, 39538.1, 42495.47, 43462.15, 
40096.07, 38241.67, 40838.54, 37298.9, 37789.89, 39731.94, 41080.4, 
43492.65, 38590.52, 43893.74, 47327.21, 50918.25, 50379.21, 54567.22, 
60506.23, 60400.85, 64222.08, 69384.93, 89144.59, 90807.88, 103747.21, 
122753.24, 156299.39, 160301.01, 123625.03, 123852.21, 119317.25, 
143581.44, 139733.44, 138287.63, 140611.01, 132821.9, 134174.05, 
119873.91, 104745.2, 102568.08, 108495.29, 104139.22, 107310.34, 
96652.77, 97559.14, 97458.09, 99645.86, 99518.62, 88783.57, 87350.12, 
88366.05, 85797.72, 79371.51, 85177.74, 79200.8, 80809.09, 88289.82, 
107608.45, 106483.75, 117233.06, 109033.58, 107339.81, 119945.76, 
97069.41, 99109.49, 102120.63, 104637.36, 99037.93, 102048.79, 
102037.58, 95501.08, 89401.56, 94067.22, 88651.45, 87803.93, 
92049.07, 87261.11, 85317.53, 89025.08, 88552.94, 83983.73, 84168.28, 
84476.24, 81941.05, 81426.13, 77540.56, 78085.95, 74735.07, 82478.9, 
80887.16, 78835.6, 78952.48, 77544.39, 79544.62, 70455.94, 68753.77, 
65726.53, 65450.46, 67594.74, 60993.19, 61718.4, 57680.74, 59899.76, 
56735.83, 54972.42, 59443.07, 65322.55, 65478.19, 63105.32, 61492.07, 
61523.85, 62150.7, 61445.03, 63736.17, 64952.37, 65632.63, 69287.93, 
64394.79, 67278.39, 64725.48, 65203.72, 58756.86, 58543.8, 54725.53, 
56695.21, 56080.25, 56984.01, 58274.86, 58095.28, 58358.48, 53135.74, 
51768.65, 51497.63, 51252.96, 51430.46, 49082.16, 50737.68, 50127.67, 
51480.31, 53698.52, 50443.76, 52020.64, 51173.85, 53571.85, 58335.06, 
57287.2, 59972.28, 60672.52, 57987.09, 58375.7, 55420.9, 53602.28, 
54393.81, 55780.68, 56458.81, 49292.09, 51243.87, 52377.16, 48101.57, 
48220.78, 50208.24, 48765.23, 49902.39, 50793.19, 49851.52, 47532.41, 
47120.95, 46668.54, 47629.39, 44120.18, 44460.3, 45619.62, 45481.28, 
44875.08, 43087.08, 43240.65, 45569.99, 41899.63, 41874.13, 41795.6, 
41568.03, 41557.52, 41222.92, 38676.62, 38817.25, 39404.32, 40441.07, 
40416.99, 42136.42, 38903.5, 37736.97, 40092.83, 40475.44, 43721.26, 
41192.97, 39738.41, 39990.29, 38204.02, 40564.26, 38298.92, 38467.2, 
38642.5, 39078.28, 37214.24, 37907.73, 38236.85, 37096.34, 36397.87, 
33868.79, 32746.79, 32529.05, 32860.52, 33750.11, 37451.17, 37881.59, 
39124.04, 39373.31, 39920.98, 43359.35, 42136.35, 42330.2, 40990.61, 
42218.43, 41899.67, 41121.12, 41968.46, 42211.13, 43164.33, 42253.91, 
42858.84, 41943.7, 43279.41, 43104.44, 43168.42, 40272.75, 38282.53, 
38639.82, 39136.33, 40094.41, 37452.06, 37879.08, 37733.25, 38654.96, 
37570.53, 40139.85, 41052.78, 40682.66, 41121.96, 41704.14, 38601.33, 
39998.84, 34061.7, 36224.52, 32463.81, 33186.3, 34058.46, 33095.26, 
34209.99, 32714.12, 31591.44, 29333.93, 27937.54, 31834.53, 31214.06, 
29771.58, 29708.54, 30325.83, 32258.91, 28384.86, 29726.01, 29314.52, 
30487.7, 30326.26, 29539.28, 29570.61, 28880.75, 29809.53, 31342.18, 
30757.38, 31282.57, 32294.96, 32508.22, 31784.35, 33749.21, 33206.91, 
32488.36, 34916.98, 34120.39, 33919.56, 36238.09, 37764.65, 39725.93, 
39946.03, 39572.87, 40532.67, 38175.41, 36484.87, 37087.1, 39407.23, 
38823.41, 39088.39, 41202.22, 44077.95, 41077.27, 39706.49, 40160.8, 
43225.23, 41545.95, 42763.34, 43824.99, 43345.42, 42462.39, 43627.27, 
44609.51, 42313.53, 43250.55, 44079.62, 42872.92, 43463.95, 43187.69, 
43623.47, 44693.65, 45810.85, 45189.13, 46607.24, 44635.91, 43673.51, 
45410.89, 45725.4, 45711.46, 44667.34, 48435.03, 48088.75, 48149.24, 
53638.15, 54797.65, 59306.99, 60549.39, 66580.71, 64398.7, 68670.17, 
73544.8, 73207.82, 70132.24, 72380.14, 73127.19, 70750.44, 70732.33, 
74794.08, 75305.96, 78684.47, 78697.72, 78136.13, 80904.88, 80288.24, 
80333.49, 79237.75, 77894.88, 85456.14, 91017.5, 86909.73, 93142.38, 
98164.55, 101138, 92915.91, 91028.21, 93504.19, 98611.14, 99222.02, 
90401.32, 93902.94, 71869.26, 77577.05, 78842.83, 82580.29, 93148.43, 
90522.69, 86898.55, 93116.34, 90165.22, 89388.1, 88636.96, 89154.46, 
94140.79, 101284.97, 101240.8, 97771.42, 98484.63, 104232.31, 
110861.29, 109924.75, 110081.55, 101305.53, 104626.6, 109186.77, 
108480.7, 115895.78, 113993.07, 108721.1, 115603.22, 119264.31, 
124590.47, 124825.25, 121584.17, 125703.89, 138678.32, 124869.58, 
134272.93, 135541.96, 117795.12, 132980, 143263.78, 136815.43, 
131844.03, 122170.56, 127544.3, 126678.19, 129077.53, 138172.78, 
137399.66, 142343.2, 143315.73, 151925.08, 146555, 150267.45, 
143095.27, 140809.62, 118407.31, 129287.64, 136845.88, 130162.81, 
129897.62, 128263.33, 126598.97, 127583.22, 135389.21, 133030.85, 
131620.27, 127232.12, 133216.07, 132168.67, 133570.13, 133443.96, 
130518.24, 140374.68, 144593.36, 148035.26, 145127.63, 142350.96, 
141240.52, 147846.75, 143289.4, 136086.24, 137544.97, 133418.21, 
137853.05, 130911.02, 127512.7, 134600.03, 139389.33, 139032.6, 
137558.11, 134427.93, 135495.74, 137534.85, 135422.27, 133922.96, 
133668.11, 134238.58, 133652.03, 136530.93, 140482.78, 138713.61, 
141171.16, 140022.71, 139579.19, 140057.91, 144371.2, 144432.12, 
144327.12, 143260.77, 145431.14, 146818.91, 140621.15, 140791.42, 
143696.89, 141819.72, 138506.09, 136673.12, 133333.66, 134853.78, 
137113.17, 138252.77, 140325.48, 144009.28, 146847.76, 143381.34, 
142816.14, 140664.32, 151805.65, 154996.22, 162231.99, 160523.77, 
163341.24, 159901.01, 164615.44, 171703.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-602L), class = "data.frame")
```