# Plot multiple columns on same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  id = 1:12,
  x = rnorm(12),
  y = rnorm(12),
  z = rnorm(12)
)

# base r
plot(mydf$x)
plot(mydf$y)
plot(mydf$z)
```

One of these looks like e.g.

[image]

what is the equivilent, if any in ggplot and can I display all 3 on one plot using color to separate them? Perhaps using a line?

```
mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x)) + geom_point()
Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531904/plot-multiple-columns-on-the-same-graph-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877357/how-to-plot-all-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and plot at once

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
mydf %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = rn, y = value, color = name)) + 
          geom_point()
```

It may be also better to have `geom_line` as it will show the trend more easily

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = rn, y = value, color = name)) + 
       geom_line()
```

[image]

---

Or using `base R` with `matplot`

```
matplot(as.matrix(mydf), type = 'l', col = c('red', 'green', 'blue'))
legend("topright", legend = names(mydf), fill = c('red', "green", "blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R` (and ggplot2):

```
require(ggplot2)

mydd <- setNames( data.frame( matrix( rep(c("x","y","z"), each=12) ),
 c(mydf$x, mydf$y, mydf$z) ), c("x_point","data")) # convert to long format

ggplot( mydd ) + geom_line( aes( rep(1:12, 3), data, col=x_point ) )
```

[image: ggplot2]

only `base R`:

```
plot(mydf$x, t="l", col="red", ylim=c(min(mydf[,2:4]),max(mydf[,2:4])))
lines(mydf$y, col="green")
lines(mydf$z, col="blue")
legend( "bottomleft", legend=c("x","y","z"), col=c("red","green","blue"), lwd=1 )
```

[image]