# Plotting multiple columns from dataframe in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my data:

```
> ptm <- read.csv('ptm.csv')

> ptm
               Method X1HSTB X1I6WA X1U19A X1YSAC X1YTBA X2CDSA X5O38A
1 Class weighted loss   0.37   0.83   0.44   0.49   0.76   0.64   0.68
2                  OS   0.58   0.81   0.29   0.33   0.76   0.62   0.68
3  2 phase swapped OS   0.40   0.81   0.29   0.30   0.75   0.70   0.63
4        Thresholding   0.42   0.81   0.29   0.29   0.70   0.69   0.66
5  2 phase swapped US   0.43   0.80   0.27   0.29   0.71   0.66   0.54
6                  US   0.35   0.77   0.27   0.53   0.70   0.26   0.69
7          Unbalanced   0.43   0.69   0.27   0.34   0.70   0.44   0.52
8             Control   0.75   0.87   0.80   0.61   0.82   0.84   0.83
```

This is a rough idea of the plot I'd like to make:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KlX1.png

This is what I tried:

```
> ptm_plot <- ggplot(data=ptm, aes(x="1HSTB", "1I6WA", "1U19A", "1YSAC",      
"1YTBA","2CDSA", "5O38A",
  y=X1HSTB, X1I6WA, X1U19A, X1YSAC, X1YTBA, X2CDSA, X5O38A, colour=Method)) + 
  geom_point(stat="identity")
> ptm_plot
```

This was the result:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZveLo.png

It's close to what I want but I can't seem to get all my columns in there.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have to reshape to long. Makes life much easier, i.e. try `ptm %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-Method) %>% ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, colour=Method)) + geom_point()`

Comment: Possible dup: [Plot multiple columns on same plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315116/plot-multiple-columns-on-same-plot), [Plot multiple columns on the same graph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531904/plot-multiple-columns-on-the-same-graph-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to reshape to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ptm %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -Method) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = Method)) + 
    geom_point(stat = 'identity')
```